# How find Apache Server processes, idle workers values on a running system

Tags: linux, apache, http

On a running linux system.

how to find out Active StartServers (running as of now), number of active child processes and  idle workers using oS commands or any other tools ?

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 5):

```
apache2ctl status
```

And

```
apache2ctl fullstatus
```

Or apachectl depending on your setup.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html
You need to have mod_status enabled.